# How can we apply 3 classes for 1 div at a time?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply classes (.text1  .text2  .text3) for one div.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 14):

In HTML, write it like this :

```
<div class="text1 text2 text3"></div>
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Xee/)

In Javascript, do this :

```
myDiv.className = "text1 text2 text3";
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fP7gb/)

Answer (score 0):

in css it's like this:

```
.text1.text2.text3 { 
    color: #BADA55;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following selector to target a div that has all 3 classes

```
.text1.text2.text3 {

}
```